# Acceso a JSON externo bloqueado por CORS

Tags: cors

Tengo un fichero HTML que llama a un script.

Dicho script es externo, el cual hace llamadas a otros script que me dan el siguiente error:

> test.min.js?v=5&lang=en&key=5454545:192 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file://test.com/maps/data_en.json' from origin 'null' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for
>   protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Este problema se soluciona si ejecuto el HTML en un web server, pero yo quiero que un usuario pueda abrir dicho HTML y ejecutarlo directamente de modo local sin necesidad de web server.

¿Puedo hacer algo para evitar este error o solo podría en el caos de acceder a los script externos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De tu error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file://test.com/maps/data_en.json'
```

XMLHttpRequest Significa, literalmente "petición HTTP para obtener XML". Si bien el acrónimo AJAX ha quedado desfasado en cuanto a lo de XML (puedes pedir JSON o cualquier otro tipo/formato de datos), lo que no varía es lo de hacer una petición HTTP.

Sólo un servidor HTTP podrá responder a peticiones HTTP, por lo que intentar cargar un fichero local mediante una llamada AJAX fallará siempre, incluso si el fichero Javascript no tuviese el problema de CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo la solución para chrome, debes ejecutar el siguiente comando en la consola y te ejecutara una ventana del navegador deshabilitando el bloqueo del CORS.

```
"[PATH_TO_CHROME]\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp
```

Fuente:
https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/

Comment: El voto negativo no es mío, pero esto está bien sólo para desarrolladores, desactivar la seguridad del navegador por defecto es una idea... peligrosa

Comment: Ejecutar Chrome así no soluciona el problema que plantea el OP, que es que los usuarios puedan acceder al script. Además de que plantea un problema grave de seguridad.

Comment: El voto negativo es mío @Pablo Lozano, no creo que sea buena idea sugerir que se deshabilite el módulo de seguridad 

Comment: Yo siempre lo he utilizado así en modo desarrollo por lo que entendí era para eso que lo quería ya que cuando lo termine lo lógico es que este todo en el mismo servidor